# Device brightness not set proper in android

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

I want to change the brightness using seekBar it changes but the notification brightness bar progress is not the same as the progress value.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
    private SeekBar seekBright;
    private TextView txtProgress;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
       
        seekBright=findViewById(R.id.seekBright);
        txtProgress=findViewById(R.id.txtProgress);

        if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT> Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
            boolean canWriteSettings = Settings.System.canWrite(this);
            if (!canWriteSettings) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_WRITE_SETTINGS);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        }
        
        seekBright.setMax(255);
        seekBright.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int i, boolean b) {
                setScreenBrightness(MainActivity.this,i);
                txtProgress.setText(i+"/"+seekBar.getMax
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }
        });
        //  finally use the below method to set the brightness

        new LoadApplications().execute();
    }
    public void setScreenBrightness(Context mContext, int brightnessValue){
        // Make sure brightness value between 0 to 255
        if(brightnessValue >= 0 && brightnessValue <= 255){
            Settings.System.putInt(
                    mContext.getContentResolver(),
                    Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS,
                    brightnessValue
            );
        }
    }
}
```

This Output of my code

[image: When set 0 from my app]

When set to 0 progress is displayed anywhere.

[image]

[image]

when set to 1 it displays proper

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

** Screenshot emulator version I SDK-33**

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem too. I did a lot of searches and built it together:

```
public class Brightness extends AppCompatActivity {

    SeekBar seekBar;
    TextView br_value;
    Handler handler = new Handler();
    Runnable refresh;
    public static int CODE_WRITE_SETTINGS_PERMISSION = 42;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_brightness);

        seekBar = findViewById(R.id.seekBar);
        br_value = findViewById(R.id.brightness_status_info);
   
        int brightness = Settings.System.getInt(getContentResolver(), Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS, 0);
        seekBar.setMax(getMaxBrightness(getApplicationContext(), brightness));
        seekBar.setProgress(brightness);
        int br_in_perc = seekBar.getProgress();
        br_value.setText(String.valueOf(100*br_in_perc/seekBar.getMax())+" %");
        writeSettings();

        seekBar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(new SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onProgressChanged(SeekBar seekBar, int progress, boolean fromUser) {
                Context context = getApplicationContext();
                boolean canWrite = Settings.System.canWrite(context);
                if (canWrite) {
                    int sBrightness = seekBar.getMax()-(seekBar.getMax()-progress);
                    Settings.System.putInt(context.getContentResolver(), Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS_MODE, Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS_MODE_MANUAL);
                    Settings.System.putInt(context.getContentResolver(), Settings.System.SCREEN_BRIGHTNESS, sBrightness);
                    refresh = new Runnable() {
                        @SuppressLint("SetTextI18n")
                        public void run() {
                            int br_in_perc = seekBar.getProgress();
                            br_value.setText(String.valueOf(100*br_in_perc/seekBar.getMax())+" %");
                            handler.postDelayed(refresh, 100);
                        }
                    };
                    handler.post(refresh);
                } else {
                    br_value.setText(R.string.write_settings_not_allowed);
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onStartTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onStopTrackingTouch(SeekBar seekBar) {

            }
        });
    }

    public int getMaxBrightness(Context context, int defaultValue){

        PowerManager powerManager = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
        if(powerManager != null) {
            Field[] fields = powerManager.getClass().getDeclaredFields();
            for (Field field: fields) {

                //https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/os/PowerManager.java

                if(field.getName().equals("BRIGHTNESS_ON")) {
                    field.setAccessible(true);
                    try {
                        return (int) field.get(powerManager);
                    } catch (IllegalAccessException e) {
                        return defaultValue;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        return defaultValue;
    }

    public void writeSettings() {
        boolean canWrite = Settings.System.canWrite(getApplicationContext());
        if (!canWrite) {
            AlertDialog.Builder writeSettingsDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(Brightness.this, R.style.AlertDialog);
            writeSettingsDialog.setTitle(R.string.bright_alert_title)
                    .setMessage(R.string.bright_alert_text)
                    .setCancelable(false)
                    .setPositiveButton(R.string.ok, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_MANAGE_WRITE_SETTINGS);
                            startActivity(intent);
                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton(R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            finish();
                            Toast.makeText(Brightness.this, R.string.settings_cancelled, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    });
            AlertDialog alertDialog = writeSettingsDialog.create();
            alertDialog.show();
            alertDialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE).setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
            alertDialog.getButton(AlertDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE).setTextColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
        }
    }
}
```

At the end of the code is AlertDialog which checks for permission to write settings.

Hope it helps